# How to call a remote method from android application

Tags: java, android, rmi

I want to call a remotely available java method from an Android application,Here can I use rmi for android application as well? Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110629/android-networking

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can but there are disadvantages than advantages. Here are some discussion on this topic [Android forums](http://androidforums.com/application-requests/77782-rmi-android.html) and [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110629/android-networking). If possible it is better to look for alternatives like web-services.

Answer (score 1):

I would first look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321906/how-to-find-the-jar-of-java-rmi-package).

Depending on your requirements, you might want to look at the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) system for IPC between apps on a device. A simple [REST solution](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) might be a better solution if you are looking to communicate with between apps on different devices.